# gotoXY display on the screen

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I know my question is silly but I still need your help.why function of gotoxy do not work expect?

```
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    COORD coord={x,y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord);
}
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n";
   cout<<"|                |      XUAT SAC      |        GIOI        |        KHA         |     TRUNG BINH     |        YEU         |\n";
   cout<<"|     MA LOP     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
   cout<<"|                |    SL    |    %    |    SL    |    %    |    SL    |    %    |    SL    |    %    |    SL    |    %    |\n";
   cout<<"|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
   gotoxy(0,5);cout<<"gotoxy(0,5)";
}
```

and it is display this:

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
   |                |      XUAT SAC      |        GIOI        |        KHA         |     TRUNG BINH     |        YEU         |
   |     MA LOP     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------gotoxy(0,5)

I want to gotoxy(0,5)on the screen but it is display in the line of 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to gotoxy(0,5)on the screen but it is display in the line of 3

**No, it's actually displayed on line 5.**

Default console width on my platform is 120 pixels. When the line printed is too long to fit into the 120 pixels restriction windows console will automatically create a new line, hence Y=Y+1.

This code will most likely work for you since the width is shorter...

```
std::cout << "_____________________1\n";
std::cout << "_____________________2\n";
std::cout << "_____________________3\n";
std::cout << "_____________________4\n";
std::cout << "_____________________5\n";


gotoxy(0, 5); 
cout << "gotoxy(0,5)";
```

You can adjust the console width to a wider length and it should work as expected.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19982/how-to-make-the-windows-command-prompt-wider/